# Object Array get duplicates from an item and select one with biggest date

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I'm facing a problem and I'm stuck and lost so kindly get some help from the community

I have a structure in my Object Array called **items** where I have an Item (Level). This array have 4 in total.

```
  const items: any[] = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("List")
          .items.select("ID, Part, Level, MyDate")
          .filter("Part eq 1")
          .getAll();
```

My problem is manipulating the Array in order to get:

1. Get the duplicates for **Level**, in this case is (2) remove all others;
2. From that 2 remove the one with the oldest **Date**.

So I'll have only one.

Couldn't get help from my research.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for my problem, sometimes workload block us

```c
//Find the duplicates based on Level and remove all others
workItems = items

const lookup: any[] = workItems.reduce((a, e) => {
  a[e.Level] = ++a[e.Level] || 0;
  return a;
}, {});


const levels = workItems.filter(e => lookup[e.Level]);
```

```c
//Get the latest date from my duplicates and remove all older
let isLast = levels[0];
for (let date of levels) {
  if (moment(date.YourDateField) > moment(isLast.YourDateField)) {
    isLast = date;
  }
}
```